# What is the operator norm of $(c_1 x_1, c_2, x_2, \cdots)$ in $\ell^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm wondering that the operator norm $\|T\|$ where $T:\ell^p \to \ell^p$, $1\le p\le \infty$ is
$$
Tx = (c_1 x_1, c_2x_2, \cdots),
$$
where $c_k \in \mathbb C$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} c_k = 0$.

I tried as 
$$
\|Tx\|_p^p = \sum_{j=1}^\infty |c_j|^p |x_j|^p \le \cdots
$$
but I cannot find what is the smallest constant such that $\|Tx\|_p \le C \|x\|_p$ holds.

Comment: Any guesses as to what $C$ is? (Hint: try to maximize $\| Tx\|$ subject to $\|x\|=1$ by making one coordinate $1$ and the others $0$.)

Comment: @arctic tern I tried as $ \|Tx\|_p^p \le \|c\|_{\ell^\infty}^p \|x\|_p^p$ so that $\|T\| \le \|c\|_\infty$. And I took $x = (0,0,1,0,...)$ (i-th component is 1) so that $\|Tx\|_p = |c_i x_i| = |c_i|$. But I failed to show $\|T\| \ge \|c\|_\infty$. Would you please help me?

Comment: @arctictern I don't understand your reasoning. $C= \max |c_n|$ looks like the right constant to me.

Comment: @zhw, John S: Oh, sorry, I was thinking of $\|c\|_p$ even though I wrote down $\|c\|_\infty$. Yes that is the correct constant and it was what I was getting at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see why $C=\max_i|c_i|$ is the least possible constant for which $\|Tx\|\le C\|x\|$, you need to first show that equality holds for all $x$ (can you do that?) and then exhibit a nonzero $x$ for which equality is attained (do you see why that shows $C$ is the least possible bound?).

Comment: Ok now I think i can understand this