# Trying to understand the "least possible bound"

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

From this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1868830/480419)

artic tern said

> To see why $C=\max_i|c_i|$ is the least possible constant for which
>   $\|Tx\|\le C\|x\|$, you need to first show that equality holds for all
>   $x$ and then exhibit a nonzero $x$ for which
>   equality is attained (do you see why that shows $C$ is the least
>   possible bound?).

I don't really understand why that would shows C is the least possible bound.
I would really appreciated if someone can point that out to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to find the smallest constant $C$ for which we have $\Vert Tx \Vert \leq C \Vert x \Vert$. Obviously we first need to show that the inequality holds for such a $C$. That is the trivial part.

Now assume that there is a $x \neq 0$ with $\Vert Tx \Vert = C \Vert x \Vert$. Then for each $D < C$ you have that $D \Vert x \Vert < \Vert Tx \Vert$. Hence you can't have $\Vert Tx \Vert \leq D \Vert x \Vert$ for all $x \in \ell^p$. So $C$ is the smallest constant for which the inequality holds. I hope it got clear :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I got it now!